# Checking A Folder For Logs Files

Tags: bash, sh

Hello and thank you for for the help in advanced. I am trying to accomplish a simple check to see if a folder contains any files in end in .log. And if it does contain any file ending in a .log, simply copy it to another folder. I did try something like

```
if [ -f /path/to/log/*.log ]; then cp -a /path/to/log /path/to/backup/folder; fi
```

But that does not give me anything clean enough to work with.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bash array:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob # Expand to the empty string if no files are found
logfiles=( /path/to/log/*.log )
cp -a "${logfiles[@]}" /path/to/backup/
```

Or a POSIXLY_STRICT approach:

```bash
cpIfExists() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    cp "$@"
  fi
}
cpIfExists /path/to/log/*.log /path/to/backup/
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I can place this at the top of my script and use it where ever I want. I can also change the source and destination paths and this would also accommodate other file extensions. Thank you very much!

Comment: I need an amendment to this if you would be so kind. If the file exists, I would like to copy plus rename the lofgile. The new name would be the local server time.

example

    local_time="`date +"%H-%M-%S"`"
    cpIfExists() {
       if [ -f "$1" ]; then
         cp "$@"
       fi
    }
    cpIfExists /path/to/log/*.log /path/to/dated-today-folder/backup/16-26-23-THEORIGINALNAME.log 


Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check first, just copy the files:

```
cp /path/to/log/*.log /path/to/backup/folder
```

Comment: If no files are found this will cause an error as cp will try to copy the nonexistent file named `/path/to/log/*.log` unless `nullglob` is enabled.

Comment: I guess that can be an issue if you are trying to do more than just copy the files, for example, test if any files were copied.

Answer (score 0):

Not near anything to test that this works for sure, but it should:

```
for log in `ls /path/to/log | grep .log`; do
    cp /path/to/log/$log /path/to/backup/folder/
done
```

Comment: Thank you also very much sir. I can also use this on other areas of the same script. I appreciate this.